# PUT Request with Query Parameters using InMemoryDatabase Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to make a PUT request for an object that doesn't contain an exact 'id' key. I am using the Angular InMemory Database service. The Object structure is as follows:

```
{
  students: [{
    name: 'jim',
    age: 10,
    grade: 4,
  },{
    name: 'james',
    age: 11,
    grade: 5,
  }]
}
```

**Service Method**

```
updateStudent(student: Student) {
  const url = 'api/students'
  const options = { name: student.name };
  return this.httpClient.put(url, student, { params: options }).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('student updated)),
    catchError(this.handleError('updating student'))
  );
}
```

**Component Method**

```
updateStudent() {
  this.studentService.updateStudent(this.selectedStudent).subscribe();
}
```

Where selectedStudent is:

```
{
  name: 'jim',
  age: 12,
  grade: 6
}
```

If I change the PUT to a GET the in memory database come back with the correct student in the array. But with the code stated above I get a 404 Error

Comment: Is there a way where we can reproduce the issue?